# Representing relations between devices when presented with only one-to-many mappings

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, algorithm, linq

There are devices that communicate between each other. 
Already existing in the Legacy codebase is a list of one-to-many mappings between the devices. I have written a function in my backend that processes this list. Each mapping is in the form of a custom object that stores the source object and the multiple destinations that the source is mapped to.

In the front-end, I have a list of devices as checkboxes. When I select a device, I need to find out for each device, all the other devices that it is related to, both, when acting as a sender, or and as a receiver. Then I need to check those boxes as well.

My approach so far has been to iterate over each Key-Value Pair in the custom mapping list, find the source, identify the destinations in the mapping, add this to a source-destination collection.

Then, iterate over this mapping list again. But this time, because the source-destination mapping is one-to-many, I find that getting a destination, adding it to a list and backtracking towards the entire list to find out sources can be quite inefficient once the sizes get large. But I am unable to think of a more efficient way to do the same.

The current code works. But freezes the UI for a few seconds when it runs, but I think the approach and/or the usage of Data Structures can be optimized. Readability and semantic correctness is what I am looking for.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetDependentDeviceMasterSet(Dictionary<CustomDeviceStruct, List<dataTag>> externalMappingList)
{
    var sourceDestinationMappings = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    var destinationSourceMappings = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();           
    var mappings = new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();      

    foreach (var externalMapping in externalMappingList)
    {
        var sourceName = externalMapping.Key.deviceName;
        if (sourceDestinationMappings.ContainsKey(sourceName))
        {
            foreach (var data in externalMapping.Value)
            {
                var destinationName = data.deviceName;
                if((sourceDestinationMappings[sourceName]).Contains(destinationName) == false)
                { 
                    (sourceDestinationMappings[sourceName]).Add(destinationName);
                    if (destinationSourceMappings.ContainsKey(destinationName))
                    {
                        foreach (var includedSourceName in destinationSourceMappings[destinationName])
                        {
                            if (destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Contains(includedSourceName) == false)
                            {
                                destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Add(includedSourceName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                        
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var destinations = new List<string>();
            foreach (var data in externalMapping.Value)
            {
                var destinationName = data.deviceName;
                destinations.Add(destinationName);
                if (destinationSourceMappings.ContainsKey(destinationName))
                {
                    if (destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Contains(sourceName) == false)
                    {
                        destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Add(sourceName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var sources = new List<string>();
                    sources.Add(sourceName);
                    destinationSourceMappings.Add(destinationName, sources);                        
                }
            }
            sourceDestinationMappings.Add(sourceName, destinations);
        }
    }
    mappings.Add(sourceDestinationMappings);
    mappings.Add(destinationSourceMappings);
    return mappings;
}
```

And in the front-end, I process it like so :

```
private void FillAllNodesThatAreRelatedTo(TreeNode selectedDeviceNode)
{  
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in selectedDeviceNode.Parent.Nodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Text == selectedDeviceNode.Text)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[0].ContainsKey(selectedDeviceNode.Text))
        {
            var sourceDestinationMapping = this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[0][selectedDeviceNode.Text];
            if (sourceDestinationMapping.Contains(childNode.Text))
            {
                childNode.Checked = true;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                childNode.Checked = false;
                continue;
            }    
        }               

        if (this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[1].ContainsKey(selectedDeviceNode.Text))
        {
            var destinationSourceMapping = this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[1][selectedDeviceNode.Text];
            if (destinationSourceMapping.Contains(childNode.Text))
            {
                childNode.Checked = true;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                childNode.Checked = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if ((this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[0].ContainsKey(selectedDeviceNode.Text) == false) &&
            (this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[1].ContainsKey(selectedDeviceNode.Text) == false))
        {
            childNode.Checked = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

For the first line of code, using LINQ what I have tried so far to simplify it is:

```
var mappingsThatContainSource = from mapping in externalMappingList
                                where sourceDestinationMappings.ContainsKey(mapping.Key.deviceName)
                                select mapping;
```

But I am unsure if I am on the right track. 
Known issues:

1. Too much nesting. Hence, a want to try LINQ.
2. Inefficient use of Data Structures

Comment: Original question had serious issues with readability and was also misunderstood for being off-topic as a joke question. It can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/186516).

Answer (score 1):

(This is based on my answer from yesterday, so it is possible that not all names are completely in line with the ones presented above.)

---

A `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` I can understand, but a `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>` has my eye twitching uncontrollably. ;-)

Even `Dictionary<CustomDeviceStruct, List<dataTag>>` seems odd to me: why isn't `List<dataTag>` simply a property of `CustomDeviceStruct`?

---

[Don't use `ContainsKey`, use `TryGetValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16101815). That way you also avoid repeatedly using devices like `sourceDestinationMappings[sourceName]`.

---

I cannot figure out what this is supposed to do:

```
if (destinationSourceMappings.ContainsKey(destinationName))
{
    foreach (var includedSourceName in destinationSourceMappings[destinationName])
    {
        if (destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Contains(includedSourceName) == false)
        {
            destinationSourceMappings[destinationName].Add(includedSourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

As I read it, it seems like you loop through all elements of a `List<T>` to check if each element of that list is present in the list, and if it isn't (but why would that even be possible?) you add it to the list.

---

Let's try to rewrite your logic, which unfortunately intertwines various processes. Starting with the `else`, which can be simplified to this:

```
var destinations = externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

foreach (var dataTag in externalMapping.Value)
{
    var destinationName = dataTag.Name;
    if (!destinationSourceMappings.TryGetValue(destinationName, out List<string> sources))
    {
        sources = new List<string>();
    }

    sources.Add(sourceName);
    destinationSourceMappings[destinationName] = sources.Distinct().ToList();
}

sourceDestinationMappings.Add(sourceName, destinations);
```

But that still seems cluttered and too elaborate for what it does. Let's rework that some more, for instance by moving the `destinations` assignation to the end and some other small improvements:

```
foreach (var destinationName in externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.deviceName))
{
    if (!destinationSourceMappings.TryGetValue(destinationName, out List<string> sources))
    {
        sources = new List<string>();
    }

    sources.Add(sourceName);
    destinationSourceMappings[destinationName] = sources.Distinct().ToList();
}

sourceDestinationMappings.Add(sourceName,
    externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.deviceName).ToList());
```

Quite frankly, this still doesn't satisfy me. It feels inelegant. But at least it is much more readable that the original, because you don't need to parse 20+ lines to discover that two separate processes are happening inside that `else`.

BTW if `sources` was a HashSet, you wouldn't even need to do `sources.Distinct().ToList()`;

---

When looking at the `if` and the logic as a whole, I found that it could be rewritten as follows:

```
var sourceDestinationMappings = externalMappingList
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.deviceName, 
                x => x.Value.Select(dataTag => dataTag.deviceName).ToList());

foreach (var externalMapping in externalMappingList)
{
    var sourceName = externalMapping.Key.deviceName;

    if (!sourceDestinationMappings.TryGetValue(sourceName, out List<string> destinations))
    {
        destinations = new List<string>();

        foreach (var destinationName in externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.deviceName))
        {
            if (!destinationSourceMappings.TryGetValue(destinationName, out List<string> sources))
            {
                sources = new List<string>();
            }

            sources.Add(sourceName);
            destinationSourceMappings[destinationName] = sources.Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }

    destinations.AddRange(externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.deviceName));
    sourceDestinationMappings[sourceName] = destinations.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

But when I then stepped through the logic, I found that this still does a number of things that don't seem necessary. And I distilled it down to this:

```
var sourceDestinationMappings = externalMappingList
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.deviceName,
        x => x.Value.Select(dataTag => dataTag.deviceName).ToList());

foreach (var externalMapping in externalMappingList)
{
    var sourceName = externalMapping.Key.deviceName;

    foreach (var destinationName in externalMapping.Value.Select(dataTag => dataTag.deviceName))
    {
        if (!destinationSourceMappings.TryGetValue(destinationName, out List<string> sources))
        {
            sources = new List<string>();
        }

        sources.Add(sourceName);
        destinationSourceMappings[destinationName] = sources.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

---

To be honest, I am not sure this solution is 100% correct. You would need to test this yourself: take the same dataset and apply both your code and this code and see if the results match for the various scenarios. And even if they do, don't just copy-paste what I wrote: try to follow what changes I made and why I did so.

Compare for instance the last two code blocks: look at `destinations`, and notice how in the earlier version nothing happens to it that cannot be scrapped. 
 - We take the `Value` of `sourceDestinationMappings`, 
 - we then add `externalMapping.Value.Select(x => x.deviceName)` to the existing `destinations`,
 - and then we remove the duplicate entries when we assign `destinations` back to `sourceDestinationMappings[sourceName]`.

But all of that already happened in the first line:

```
var sourceDestinationMappings = externalMappingList
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.deviceName, 
                x => x.Value.Select(dataTag => dataTag.deviceName).ToList());
```

But `externalMappingList` hasn't changed since then, so all of that logic is pointless. And thus you can remove it, which means you end up with the final version.

---

As for the UI code you included here:

- Retrieve `selectedDeviceNode.Text` once and store it in a clear variable name if you're going to reuse it several times.
- Don't use `ContainsKey` when you need to use the result if the key is present. Even worse: you're using `ContainsKey` twice!
- The same logic is applied to `dependentDeviceMasterSet[0]` and `dependentDeviceMasterSet[1]`, so this obviously should have been moved to a separate method.

And then you end up with something like this:

```
private void FillAllNodesThatAreRelatedTo(TreeNode selectedDeviceNode)
{  
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in selectedDeviceNode.Parent.Nodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Text == selectedDeviceNode.Text)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var sourceContains = CheckDevice(childNode, 0);
        var destinationContains = CheckDevice(childNode, 1);

        if (!sourceContains && !destinationContains)
        {
            childNode.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckDevice(TreeNode childNode, int setId)
{
    if(this.dependentDeviceMasterSet[setId].TryGetValue(childNode.Text, out List<string> mapping)
    {
        childNode.Checked = mapping.Contains(childNode.Text);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This wasn't tested, this was written in Notepad++. Look at it as an example of reusing code.

(Also, what kind of front-end is this code for? ASP.NET WebForms? Isn't there a better way to bind a grid to data instead of looping through something?)

Comment: Thank you for your patience in adding the answer here once more. I am currently going through each section and understanding your reasoning behind each refactor.

Comment: So the line 'var sourceDestinationMappings = externalMappingList
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.deviceName,
        x => x.Value.Select(dataTag => dataTag.deviceName).ToList());' breaks during runtime saying that key already exists.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis I assumed the device name was unique. If that isn't, then you'd need to do a foreach.

Comment: Source name is definitely unique. However, each mapping has a source name and multiple destinations the source is connected to. For instance, device1 can be connected to devices 2,3,4 as per one kind of mapping . And then device 1 can also be connected to devices 3, 5, 6 as per a different mapping. The externalMappingList basically maintains a separate record for each kind of mapping and that is why I guess this crashes. But for finding out a relation, the mapping type is unimportant, so if we can somehow group all the destinations that a source is connected to, that would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear that there could be different mapping types in implementation. When i tried splitting your query into two parts and tried loading the first part and second part into lists, what it did was show up a source entry for each of the 700 mappings.